# Does native EE caching support configurable redis db indexes?

Tags: cache, caching

After combing through the redis driver cache file (/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_redis.php), it appears that an option doesn't exist to allow a user to specify a redis db index.

This is important in the event we use the same redis database for both a development and staging server.

Is this possible to accomplish another way? Or is anyone aware of plans to add this as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and digging into the actual Cache_redis.php file, I've found that there is currently not a way to specify a DB index without modifying the ExpressionEngine Core.

The only way to handle multiple dev/staging servers would be to utilize a something like the [Focus Labs Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) and configure separate Redis servers for each install.